# Year View skews days

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a FullCalendar with the year view plugin. However, on the year view, the days aren't displaying correctly. For example, 01/01/2017 displays as a Monday and not a Sunday as it should correctly be. I have attempted to modify the `fixedWeekCount` to 6 as shown in the below code but this only adds an extra week of the next month to the bottom and not to the top.

```
setDefaults({
    yearColumns: 2,
    fixedWeekCount: 6 // 5 rows per month minimum (else true or false)
});
```

It appears properly in all other views, the Year View is the only one having the issue.

It also looks like in the code, the first day should be a sunday not a monday as is displayed:

```
// year view
firstDay: 0, // start day of the week (Sunday)
yearTitleFormat: 'YYYY',
yearFormat: 'YYYY',
```

[image]

Comment: Most english calendars go from Sunday to Monday instead of starting with Monday. Probably that's the problem

Comment: Any idea where abouts to change this in the full calendar code?

Comment: I have just edited the question to show that Sunday should be the first day

Comment: silly question but are you absolutely 100% certain it's looking at 2017? Your display doesn't show the year. the 1st will be a Monday in 2018.